# show only part of the text on h-axis

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I am working on angularjs google charts.
Please find the demo [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/hmV1n05y42BRQPL0XydW?p=preview)

I want to show different value to be displayed on h-axis and tooltip.
In the below code, i want to show only the month name on the h-axis and both month and year on tooltip.
Any advices?

js code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['googlechart'])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    var chart1 = {};
    chart1.type = "ColumnChart";
     chart1.displayed = false;
    chart1.data = {
      "cols": [{
        id: "month",
        label: "Month", 
        type: "string"
      }, {
        id: "laptop-id",
        label: "Laptop",
        type: "number"
      } ],
      "rows": [{
        c: [{
          v: "January" + " 2017"
        }, {
          v: 19,

        } ]
      }, {
        c: [{
          v: "February" + " 2017"
        }, {
          v: 13
        }]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "March" + " 2017"
          }, {
            v: 24
          }

        ]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "April" + " 2017"
          }, {
            v: 24
          }
        ]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "May"+ " 2017"
          }, {
            v: 18
          } 
        ]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "June"+ " 2017"
          }, {
            v: 21
          } 
        ]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "July"+ " 2017"
          }, {
            v: 24
          } 

        ]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "August"+ " 2017"
          }, {
            v: 14
          } 
        ]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "September"+ " 2017"
          }, {
            v: 4
          } 
        ]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "October"+ " 2017"
          }, {
            v: 34
          } 
        ]
      }]
    };
    chart1.options = {
      "title": "Title goes here",
      "colors": ['#0000FF', '#009900', '#CC0000', '#DD9900'],
      "defaultColors": ['#0000FF', '#009900', '#CC0000', '#DD9900'],
      "isStacked": "true",
      "fill": 20,
       focusTarget: 'category',
        "displayExactValues": true,
      "vAxis": {
        "title": "Sales unit",
        "gridlines": {
          "count": 10
        }
      },
      "hAxis": {
       slantedText : "true",
     },

    };
    $scope.myChart = chart1;

  });
```

In the above code i'm using  `v: "January" + " 2017"`  , i want to show only first part i.e.,**January** to be displayed on h-axis and **January 2017** on the tooltip when mouse over on the bar(same thing february,march..on the h-axis and on the tooltip show complete text for the individual bars).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a real date for the column value

this will allow `hAxis.format` and `hAxis.ticks` for the axis labels

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
  "cols": [{
  id: "month",
  label: "Month",
  type: "date"
  }, {
  id: "laptop-id",
  label: "Laptop",
  type: "number"
  } ],
  "rows": [{
   c: [
    {
    v: new Date(2017, 0, 1),
    f: "January 2017"
    },
    {v: 119}
  ]
  }, {
    c: [
    {
    v: new Date(2017, 1, 1),
    f: "February 2017"
    },
    {v: 022}
    ]
  }, {
    c: [
    {
    v: new Date(2017, 2, 1),
    f: "March 2017"
    },
    {v: 033}
    ]
  }, {
    c: [
    {
    v: new Date(2017, 3, 1),
    f: "April 2017"
    },
    {v: 044}
    ]
  }, {
    c: [
    {
    v: new Date(2017, 4, 1),
    f: "May 2017"
    },
    {v: 055}
    ]
  }, {
    c: [
    {
    v: new Date(2017, 5, 1),
    f: "June 2017"
    },
    {v: 066}
    ]
  }, {
    c: [
    {
    v: new Date(2017, 6, 1),
    f: "July 2017"
    },
    {v: 077}
    ]
  }, {
    c: [
    {
    v: new Date(2017, 7, 1),
    f: "August 2017"
    },
    {v: 088}
    ]
  }, {
    c: [
    {
    v: new Date(2017, 8, 1),
    f: "September 2017"
    },
    {v: 099}
    ]
  }, {
    c: [
    {
    v: new Date(2017, 9, 1),
    f: "October 2017"
    },
    {v: 010}
    ]
  }]
  });

  options = {
    "title": "Title goes here",
    "colors": ['#0000FF', '#009900', '#CC0000', '#DD9900'],
    "defaultColors": ['#0000FF', '#009900', '#CC0000', '#DD9900'],
    "isStacked": "true",
    "fill": 20,
    focusTarget: 'category',
    "displayExactValues": true,
    "vAxis": {
      "title": "Sales unit",
      "gridlines": {
        "count": 10
      }
    },
    "hAxis": {
      slantedText : "true",
      format: "MMM"
    }
  };

  options.hAxis.ticks = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    options.hAxis.ticks.push(data.getValue(i, 0));
  }

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Please find the updated link with the code you suggested above, https://plnkr.co/edit/DMrKDI8eIRkUGoqQ4RwO?p=preview . It is not showing the text on tooltip and h-axis as expected.

Comment: Any suggestions on the below shown demo example would be helpful.
https://plnkr.co/edit/IQDvlXWZZoPKeNluq3Bt?p=preview
I want to show the value of V: on h-axis and value of f: on the tooltip, but dont want to use any extra js files(loader.js). Is it possible to do?